# How to prevent event bubbling from anchor triggering more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function I'm using that works except that it fires 2-3 times due to bubbling.

I am using this event listener:

```
$("body").on("click", "a", function(e){
    ...
});
```

So that anchors added later on are still caught. However, when I click an anchor it triggers 2-3 times this way. if I change it to:

```
$("a").on("click", function(e){
    ...
});
```

It fires only once and works perfectly.

I've tried various combinations of `e.stopPropagation`, `e.stopImmediatePropagation`, `e.preventDefault` and have not been able to get the first event listener to only trigger once.

**Update:**

When preparing a snippet for this question, I solved my problem: but I would like to know why it caused the problem described above.

A little background: I am making a script that simulates the jQuery mobile page changes, without needing the jQm library. This is the bit of code causing the problem:

```
$("body").on("click", "a", function(e){
    var $this = $(this);
    var $parent = $(".page:visible");
    var back = $this.data("rel");
    var targetLink = $this.attr("href")
    if(targetLink.substr(0,1) == "#"){
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        if(back == "back" && $hist.length > 0){
            var $prev = $hist.pop();
            $("#title").text($prev.data("title"));
            $prev.css({left: "-100%", display: "block"});
            $parent.animate({left: "100%"},500, function(){
                $parent.hide();
            });
            $prev.animate({left: "0%"}, 500, function(){
                $prev.trigger("pageChange");
            });
        }else if(back != "back"){
            $hist.push($parent);
            if(targetLink != "#" && targetLink != ""){
                var $target = $(targetLink);
                if(!$target.is($parent)){
                    $("#title").text($target.data("title"));
                    $target.css({left: "100%", display: "block"});
                    $parent.animate({left: "-100%"},500, function(){
                        $parent.hide();
                    });
                    $target.animate({left: "0%"}, 500, function(){
                        $target.trigger("pageChange");
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The problem occurs when using a back button, it triggers 2-3 times and ends up going "back" before the first page leaving the screen blank. The problem seems to be the positioning of the `$hist.push($parent)` bit. By relocating it as so:

```
}else if(back != "back"){
    if(targetLink != "#" && targetLink != ""){
        $hist.push($parent);
        var $target = $(targetLink);
        if(!$target.is($parent)){
            $("#title").text($target.data("title"));
            $target.css({left: "100%", display: "block"});
            $parent.animate({left: "-100%"},500, function(){
                $parent.hide();
            });
            $target.animate({left: "0%"}, 500, function(){
                $target.trigger("pageChange");
                //console.log("changeBtnForward");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The problem stops. $hist is acting similarly to jQuery Mobiles hash navigation to store previous pages, so when you go "back" it pops the last 'page' off the $hist object and navigates to it. Whenever you click a page link, it adds the page that link is on to the $hist object.

I can't see exactly why that causes a problem when you bind to the `body` element and not the `a` element.

Comment: Delegated event handlers wouldn't cause that, something else is going on !

Comment: Could you create a code snippet that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: I'll try and extract what I can. I suspect adeneo is correct, and my issue lies elsewhere as a snippet with just the event handlers doesn't duplicate the issue.

Comment: I agree that the issue is somewhere else, as I have used similar snippets all the time without encountering this issue. That said, apropos, this morning I ran into exactly the issue you're describing. I can't help, though: I have no idea why it's doing that, either. :p

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use `$('a').click(function (){
   //do stuff here
}` 
 for i think yor code generates two clicks :one on body and other on anchor

Comment: Because any anchor elements that are added after the script loads will not be detected by that snippet. As I state, when I bind to just the anchor it works fine.